# Building Complex header table from JSON Array with Datatable or HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, datatable

I have a JSON array of Objects which is loaded by Ajax. JSON is simple records from database I need to show it in Datatable or generate simple HTML table. Problem is that data is in simple row format but I need to display it in table with complex header and some row and column are also calculated from other columns eg. average salary. JSON data is also dynamic which is have data of 1 Month or more than one Month.

Below is the sample JSON data

```
[
    {
        "str": "41",
        "div": "Industries Div",
        "cat": "OFFICER",
        "mon": "Feb-2020",
        "sal": "4949892"
    },
    {
        "str": "248",
        "div": "Head Office",
        "cat": "OFFICER",
        "mon": "Feb-2020",
        "sal": "35394485"
    },
    {
        "str": "739",
        "div": "Health Div",
        "cat": "OFFICER",
        "mon": "Feb-2020",
        "sal": "96792134"
    },
    {
        "str": "2700",
        "div": "Education Div",
        "cat": "OFFICER",
        "mon": "Feb-2020",
        "sal": "111993656"
    },
    {
        "str": "567",
        "div": "Head Office",
        "cat": "STAFF",
        "mon": "Feb-2020",
        "sal": "31487211"
    },
    {
        "str": "2298",
        "div": "Education Div",
        "cat": "STAFF",
        "mon": "Feb-2020",
        "sal": "66639233.6"
    },
    {
        "str": "3865",
        "div": "Health Div",
        "cat": "STAFF",
        "mon": "Feb-2020",
        "sal": "140546070"
    },
    {
        "str": "241",
        "div": "Head Office",
        "cat": "OFFICER",
        "mon": "Jan-2020",
        "sal": "33243002"
    },
    {
        "str": "723",
        "div": "Health Div",
        "cat": "OFFICER",
        "mon": "Jan-2020",
        "sal": "94086161"
    },
    {
        "str": "2682",
        "div": "Education Div",
        "cat": "OFFICER",
        "mon": "Jan-2020",
        "sal": "112367649"
    },
    {
        "str": "549",
        "div": "Head Office",
        "cat": "STAFF",
        "mon": "Jan-2020",
        "sal": "30342281"
    },
    {
        "str": "2269",
        "div": "Education Div",
        "cat": "STAFF",
        "mon": "Jan-2020",
        "sal": "66289864"
    },
    {
        "str": "3852",
        "div": "Health Div",
        "cat": "STAFF",
        "mon": "Jan-2020",
        "sal": "139230281"
    }
]
```

And this is the screen shot of excel table in which format I need to build table

[image]

I have tried to build data table but having problem with multiple dynamic headers. I have tried and transform data and merged record based on Month and department. But it did not fulfill the requirements.

Below is the screenshot of datatable I have build so far

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan` and `colspan` on the HTML DOM to setup the complex headers accordingly before initializing the data table.

This is a working example of multiple headers: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: Thanks for replaying but how I will map data to column and also columns are also dynamic. Top most header is month with can be  dynamic

Comment: That mapping is up to your application logic. The final result should be like what DataTable expects.